# OCaml parser for ANTLR or JFlex

Tags: ocaml, antlr, antlr4, lexer, jflex

I'm looking for grammar files of the OCaml language written in ANTLR4 or JFlex.

If they already exist somewhere, where I can find them? Else, how can I generate or write one of them by myself?

Comment: I don't think there's an Antlr4 grammar. Looks like you'll have to scrape https://askra.de/software/ocaml-doc/4.02/full-grammar.html or better https://ocaml.org/manual/language.html. If there was a BNF, Trash or BNFC might be able to convert it to Antlr4. Otherwise, you could scrape it from the source, https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/tree/trunk/parsing.

Comment: The biggest grammars repository is located here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 You can search there or request for a new grammar, maybe somebody will implement it someday.

Comment: There is also an SDF3 specification for OCaml grammar, for what it worths
https://eelcovisser.org/talks/2020/08/28/ocaml/